# Why does our Password-Cracking Tool not work

Tags: linux, bash

we have the task to write a PasswordCracker Shell script for university. We have to use a given dictionary and have created a .txt file with our given names and passwords. But our script doesn't work and we don't know why :( Could anybody please help? We are new with the bash scripts and unix, so maybe it could only be a beginner mistake ^^

```
dictionary="/usr/share/dict/words"
userPasswords="userPasswords.txt"

while read password; do

                user=$(echo $password | sed -e "s:\ .*::g")
                passwordLog=$(echo $passwordLog | sed -e "s:.*\ ::g")
                salt=$(echo $password | sed -e "s:.*\ [$]1[$]::g" -e "s:[$].*::g")

                while read word; do

                        #opennssl actual passsword
                        wantedValue=$(openssl passwd -1 -salt $salt $word)

                        #constant user
                        if [[ $wantedValue == $passwordLog ]]; then

                                echo $user: password $word and salt $salt
                                break
done < $dictionary

                        fi

done < $userPasswords
```

Comment: So, do you get any output?  Have you tried adding `echo` commands at certain places?  Is `/usr/share/dict/words` a text file or a directory?

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work` ? You can also use `set -x` at the begining to see what values are used in your script

Comment: Also, your script has errors in it : copy it inside https://www.shellcheck.net/ to have tips on how to improve it

Comment: `fi` needs to be before `done`.

Comment: Instead of using `sed` to split up the line, use `while read user passwordLog`

Comment: Remember to quote all your variables.

Comment: No I don't get any output. I've put the done under the fi and quoted the variables. But nothing happens.

Comment: I corrected everything shellcheck.net said, but nothing changed :(

Comment: And /usr/share/dict/words is a directory, the .txt file is userPasswords.txt

Comment: Either you withhold an error message, or you are mistaken to think _/usr/share/dict/words is a directory_.

Comment: sample "userPasswords.txt" content missing